How can I get the (index tree) contents of a file with staged changes in VS Code?
The VSCode Git extension provides the Repository.diffIndexWithHead() API to return a list of files in the staged changes. I need to retrieve the content/text of a staged file. How can I achieve this within a VSCode extension? I'm developing an extension that requires access to staged changes.

I assume you don't need the VS Code API to do this part. Use the NodeJS API to execute the git command to show the index tree contents for a file (git show :file- see How can I get content of a file from git index?), and take the standard output of that command.
